# Unable to search object array value via a Angular pipe

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lodash

I'm trying search an object array with the user typed value in a textbox in Angular 4. I'm using pipe for this. I want return the values in object array by the name while passing search text.

For example :

```
arrayItems = [{
        name: 'Cam1',
        image: 'https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-OuIrYzKE1lM/WJ1nqskJ5pI/AAAAAAAAOww/v9JfD7Hb_Fwe_K1svBN7gz2A_BUKxbqGwCLcB/s400/mindblowing-awasome-wallpapers-imgs.jpg',
        lastCapturedDate: '11/20/2019 6.20PM'
    },
    {
        name: 'Cam2',
        image: 'https://akm-img-a-in.tosshub.com/indiatoday/559_102017023826.jpg?TZlWXro5W8Rj4VbO.MpENgo1F2MX93j',
        lastCapturedDate: '11/20/2019 6.20PM'
    }
];
```

**In the above array if I entered the value `Ca` in the text field it should return the both the objects.
If I write `Cam1` then it should return specific object cam1 only.**

Here is my code :

**app.component.html :**

```
<div class="col col-md-4 filter-by-cam">
    <input type="text" name="search" value="search" [(ngModel)]="search" #searchSnaps="ngModel" (keyup)="searchSnapshot(searchSnaps.value)" />
</div>

<div *ngFor="let item of snapShotArray | snapShotFilter: search; let i = index; ">
    <img id="img{{i}}" src="{{item.image}}" crossOrigin="Anonymous">
    <div>
        <span> {{item.name}}</span>
        <p>Last captured: {{item.lastCapturedDate}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts :**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  public search: string;
  snapShotArray = [
    {
      name: "Cam1",
      image:
        "https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-OuIrYzKE1lM/WJ1nqskJ5pI/AAAAAAAAOww/v9JfD7Hb_Fwe_K1svBN7gz2A_BUKxbqGwCLcB/s400/mindblowing-awasome-wallpapers-imgs.jpg",
      lastCapturedDate: "11/20/2019 6.20PM"
    },
    {
      name: "Cam2",
      image:
        "https://akm-img-a-in.tosshub.com/indiatoday/559_102017023826.jpg?TZlWXro5W8Rj4VbO.MpENgo1F2MX93j",
      lastCapturedDate: "11/20/2019 6.20PM"
    }
  ];

  public searchSnapshot(name: string) {
    console.log(name);
    this.search = name;
  }

  OnInit() {}
}
```

**pipe.ts :**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({ name: "snapShotFilter" })
export class SnapshotFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(snapshotArr: any, searchValue: string) {
    if (!snapshotArr) {
      return [];
    }
    if (!searchValue) {
      return snapshotArr;
    }
    if (snapshotArr && searchValue) {
      return snapshotArr.filter(snapshot => {
        snapshot.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase());
      });
    }
  }
}
```

For now when I try entering a value like `C` entire displayed array vanishes from the template. But when I remove it. Entire array returns to view. I dont get what is going on here. Any help would be appreciated.

Please find the [StackBlitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zqsypg).

Comment: Just a small advice, that filter pipes are considered bad practice https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe.

Comment: Yes I've heard of it.. Other than that is there any other option available?

Comment: Of course. You would need to prefilter your data in component and use this prefiltered data in the html template instead of `snapShotArray`. You already have the `searchSnapshot` method. Just do the filtering there. A little bit further advanced you could use rxjs operators to debounce the input, so not every keyup will do the filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The issue is you have not returned the object inside the filter if the condition is match. Other things are fine.**

```
if (snapshotArr && searchValue) {
      return snapshotArr.filter(snapshot => {
        return snapshot.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase());
    });
 }
```

**[Demo Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-brvoxu)**

Comment: Or simply remove the curly braces inside the arrow function

Answer (score 1):

You just need to return from the arrow function inside the filter.

**return** snapshot.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase());

The sample code is below:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({ name: "snapShotFilter" })
export class SnapshotFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(snapshotArr: any, searchValue: string) {
    if (!snapshotArr) {
      return [];
    }
    if (!searchValue) {
      return snapshotArr;
    }
    if (snapshotArr && searchValue) {
      return snapshotArr.filter(snapshot => {
       return snapshot.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase());
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Actually its a arrow functions. Since you opened the function curly braces, you need to return from function, If you dont open the function braces, you can do it without return aswell.

Adding that code aswell :

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({ name: "snapShotFilter" })
export class SnapshotFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(snapshotArr: any, searchValue: string) {
    if (!snapshotArr) {
      return [];
    }
    if (!searchValue) {
      return snapshotArr;
    }
    if (snapshotArr && searchValue) {
      return snapshotArr.filter(snapshot => snapshot.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase()));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
if (snapshotArr && searchValue) {
  return snapshotArr.filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase()))
}
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dkfq1b?embed=1&file=src/app/SnapshotFilterPipe.ts)**

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments filter pipe is a bad practice. I created you an reactive example with the debounce. Please note, this example is based on reactive form, but you are using a template driven form. You can still create a similar observable with template driven forms, but it might be a little bit more complicated.

Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  public search: FormControl = new FormControl();

  filteredSnapShots$: Observable<MySnapShot[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredSnapShots$ = this.search.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(this.search.value), // initial emit
      debounceTime(250), // emits last value after user stopped typing for 250ms
      distinctUntilChanged(), // doesn't emit same value again
      map(searchValue => searchValue ? snapShotArray.filter(snapshot => snapshot.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase())): snapShotArray), // I put as a constant
    );
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<div class="col col-md-4 filter-by-cam">
    <input placeholder="search" type="text" name="search" [formControl]="search"/>
</div>

    <div *ngFor="let item of (filteredSnapShots$ | async); let i = index; ">
        <img  id="img{{i}}" src="{{item.image}}" crossOrigin="Anonymous">
        <div>
            <span> {{item.name}}</span>
            <p>Last captured: {{item.lastCapturedDate}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Try it out with stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uq5qmp